Problem after Push Content Type to Site Hub
I just added my first new content type in awhile and deployed it to all of my (200) or so sites. When I created a new site, all of that site's document libraries got inundated with that content type. It was added to each library AND a view was created based on it. Stunk.
I did some digging and realized that I clicked "Push to Hub Sites." Some further inspection yielded this URL which says this:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/syntex/push-content-type-to-hub][1]

After the settings are updated, the content type with these settings
will be available in any newly associated site with the hub in a few
minutes. The default library view will be changed to one of these
automatically created views. If there are multiple content types
pushed to the same library, then the latest one (based on the order of
the action of pushing those content types to the hub this library
belongs to) is what will be set as the default view. Then, any new
list or library created will have the content type automatically added
to it within a few minutes of creation. A pushed content type will be
added to a document library only if it derives directly or indirectly
from the Document content type, and a content type will be added to a
list only if it does not derive from the Document content type
directly or indirectly.

Is this the problem or is there something else I'm missing?

It is normal for Push to Hub Sites. Just as the article explains, the content type will be added everywhere.
If you want to just Publish the content type and make available for the sites, use Publish option:


Thanks. Dont understand who that feature is for.
